# I am having trouble aligning my navigation bar within my CSS grid layout, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, navbar, css-grid

> I'm currently working on a web development bootcamp project where I need to create a tribute page. I've designed   the page and started working on the HTML and CSS files, but I've run into a problem I can't seem to solve.
> I am using a CSS grid layout, and the navigation bar is supposed to start at 2nd column, but it's extending outside the grid boundaries. I have targeted each .item to their own column in the grid, but it's still not working. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I've attached an image of the design for reference.
> Any help would be greatly appreciated!
>
> [Current webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in5fX.jpg)
> [grid design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmA2v.jpg)
> [Webpage design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcMCl.jpg)
>
> I've tried to paste and indent the html and css on stack overflow however it doesn't seem to be working out with me so i have attached the codes as images.
> [CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liLit.jpg)
> [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9lCk.jpg)

```css
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
        
        @import url("https://use.typekit.net/vfi6ite.css");
        
        @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { 
            
            nav {
                background: #46022b;
                display: grid;
                width: 1980px;
                grid-template-rows: 1/4;
                grid-template-columns: 1/8; /* only column intially */
            }    
              
            .main-nav {
                display: grid;
                width: 1980px;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: auto;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                padding: .5rem 1rem;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
                font-family: elza, sans-serif;
                align-self: top;
                justify-self: top;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 16px; 
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            
            .item1 {
                grid-column: 2;
                color: #fce3f7;
                text-decoration: none; 
            }    
                
            .item2 {
                grid-column: 3;
                color: #fce3f7;
                text-decoration: none; 
            }
            
            .item3 {
                grid-column: 6;
                color: #fce3f7;
                text-decoration: none; 
            }
            
            .item4 {
                grid-column: 7;
                color: #fce3f7;
                text-decoration: none; 
            }
        
            h1 {
                display: grid;
                grid-column: 4 / 6;
                grid-row: 1;
                align-self: center;
                justify-self: center;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-family: elza, sans-serif;
                font-weight: 900;
                font-style: normal;
            }
            
            .title {
                display: grid;
                align-items: center;
                grid-column: 5 / 7;
                grid-row: 4;
            }
        
            .name {
                display: grid;
                grid-column: 5 / 7;
                grid-row: 4;
                padding-bottom: 68px;
                padding-left: 185px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-family: elza, sans-serif;
                align-self: top;
                justify-self: top;
                font-weight: 900;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 43px;  
            }
        
            .subname {
                display: grid;
                grid-column: 5 / 7;
                grid-row: 4;
                padding-top: 89px;
                padding-left: 106px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-family: elza, sans-serif;
                align-self: bottom;
                justify-self: bottom;
                font-weight: 900;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 43px; 
            }
        
            .paragraph1 {
                display: grid;
                grid-column: 2 / 5;
                grid-row: 7;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-family: elza, sans-serif;
                align-self: center;
                justify-self: center;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            
            .paragraph2 {
                display: grid;
                grid-column: 3;
                grid-row: 3/5;
                align-self: center;
                justify-self: center;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: elza, sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-style: normal;
            }
            
            .paragraph3 {
                display: grid;
                grid-column: 6;
                grid-row: 5/8;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding-bottom: 28.34px;
                font-family: elza, sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        .special-font {
                font-family: elza,sans-serif;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 20px;  
        }
        
        .Zahraa {
                display: grid;
                grid-column: 1/8;
                grid-row: 1/7;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding-left: 87px;
        }
        
            .grid-container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 222.49px);
                grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 117.49px);
                grid-column-gap: 20.01px;
                grid-row-gap: 20.01px;
        }
        }
```

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
          <head>
             <meta charset="UTF-8">
             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
             <title>Tribute</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tribute.css">
          </head>
          <body>
             <div class="grid-container">
                <nav>
                   <ul class="main-nav">
                      <li><a class="item1" href="/">Personality</a></li>
                      <li><a class="item2" href="#Hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
                      <li><a class="item3" href="#Work Ethic">Work Ethic</a></li>
                      <li><a class="item4" href="#Attitude">Attitude</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1>TRIBUTE</h1>
                <h1 class="title">
                   <span class="name">ZAHRAA</span> 
                   <span class="subname">AL-TAYYAR</span>
                </h1>
                <h3 class="paragraph1">
                   <p>We met in <span class="special-font">architecture school</span> at the University of Westminster. We were both in the same class and shared the same passion for designing and creating. We quickly became friends and started to spend a lot of time together, <span class="special-font">studying and working on projects. </span>We bonded over our shared love for art and design and soon realized that we had a lot in common.
                      We went on a holiday together to <span class="special-font">Greece and Italy</span>, where we explored the ancient ruins and architecture of both countries. 
                   </p>
                </h3>
                <h3 class="paragraph2">
                   <p>Zahraa is an individual of munificent proclivities, a characteristic that is exemplified by her willingness to allot her time, resources, and support to those in her ambit. Furthermore, her predilection for adventure leads her to constantly seek out new experiences and locales, infusing her relationships with a sense of <span class="special-font">exhilaration and vitality. </span>Additionally, her disposition is marked by an innate purity of heart. </p>
                </h3>
                <h3 class="paragraph3">Zahraa is person who is <span class="special-font">generous, adventurous, and pure-hearted </span>and is a wonderful friend to have. She is willing to give of herself, her time, resources, or support, to help those around her. Her <span class="special-font">adventurous spirit </span>leads her to try new things and explore new places, bringing excitement and energy to her relationships. She has a <span class="special-font">pure heart</span>, a rare and valuable trait that means she is <span class="special-font">genuine, kind and compassionate.</span> She has good intentions, easy to trust and confide in, which makes her the type of person that can foster deep connections and a sense of understanding.</h3>
                <img class="Zahraa" src="zahraaPS.png" alt="A photo of Zahraa">
             </div>
             <footer>
                <h4>
                   (c) Safa Husain 2023
                </h4>
             </footer>
          </body>
       </html>
```

> Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if that's what you want to achieve, but if you check your CSS properties in any browser's Developer Tools, it says:
`grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` with respective values `1/4` and `1/8` are incorrect.

What you most probably wanted to achieve is to tell browser where they should start and where to end and to do so you have to use different properties:
`grid-row-start/-end` and `grid-column-start/-end` or shortcuts  `grid-row` and `grid-column`.

Apply this to `nav` element:

```css
grid-column: 1/8;
grid-row: 1/4;
```